# Understanding the Java regex pattern example

Tags: java, regex

I have a Java regular expressions example that works and extract content from given input string based on the given pattern:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class PatternEx {
    static Pattern PATTERN_ONE = Pattern.compile("^(/?test/[^/]+)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$");
    static Pattern PATTERN_TWO = Pattern.compile("^(/?test)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$");
    static Pattern[] PATTERNS = { PATTERN_ONE, PATTERN_TWO };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (Pattern p : PATTERNS) {
            Matcher m = p.matcher("/test/hello/world/checking/");
            if (m.matches()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
world
hello
```

I have gone through the [Java doc for regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) and based on the document I can see that the pattern here is using "[Capturing Groups](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)"

But I am not able to understand how the pattern in my example works, what is its meaning and how it is able to extract data from input string. Can someone please help me in understanding this code.

Comment: Do you have an understanding of what regex `anchors` `literals` and `modifiers` are? If not I'd suggest googling a basic regex tutorial. Once you understand what they are and what they represent you will find that your presented example is easily decipherable by utilizing that specific knowledge.

Comment: @CeilingGecko, the Java official doc do not give that information, can you please suggest some link where I can learn them - `anchors literals and modifiers`

Comment: Please note that regex is not a java exclusive thing. Start here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html :)

Comment: And the details of the Java regex can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps:

Pattern 1: `^(/?test/[^/]+)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$`

```
group 1: (/?test/[^/]+) = "/test/hello"
group 2: ([^/]+) = "world"
group 3: (/?.*) = "/checking/"
```

Pattern 2: `^(/?test)/([^/]+)(/?.*)$`

```
group 1: (/?test) = "/test"
group 2: ([^/]+) = "hello"
group 3: (/?.*) = "world/checking/"
```

Hints:

```
/?test - the slash is optional = "test", "/test"
[^/] - anything else than a slash = "hello", "world", "$#* abc",...
[^/]+ - the plus stands for 1 or more times = "a", "aa",...
/?.* - optional slash and any character 0 or more times = "","/","a","/a",...
```

^,$,?,.,*,[] - regex operators, you can google their meaning.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, can you please provide some explanation to it, I am not able to understand this clearly.